# cURL error 3 on Forest Admin

Tags: laravel, curl, forestadmin

I'm trying to install Forest Admin on a Laravel project. I had follow the step of installation but when I run the command :

```
php artisan forest:send-apimap
```

I have this error :

```
In CurlFactory.php line 162:



cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Thanks for your help and excuse my english, i'm french !

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create an issue in the Github repository (https://github.com/ForestAdmin/forest-laravel).

Please provide as much details as you can (at least PHP, Laravel, and Forest Liana versions), it will make the debug process more efficient.

Thank you Bendl!